# VBA Changing cell content within sheet range

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this code , which should go over 2 sheets and change data within if matching the 'if' statement.

For some reason it works for the first sheet but not for the second. Any thoughts?

```
   Sheets("Open - Software Evaluation").Select
   For iRow = 2 To 100
          If Cells(iRow, "E") = "Under Software Evaluation/Fix" Then
             Cells(iRow, "E") = "Evaluation - R&D"
             Else     
           End If
   Next iRow

   Sheets("Open - Pending Client Review").Select
   For iRow = 2 To 100
   If Cells(iRow, "E") = "Pending Client Review/Approval" Then
       Cells(iRow, "E") = "Client Review/Approval"
   Else    
   End If
   Next iRow
```

Comment: The code runs fine for me. I suggest you debug it - have you got exactly "Pending Client Review/Approval" in the E column in this sheet?

Comment: The code runs fine for me too, or maybe it's that you are not selecting the Correct sheet?  Just run the code in debug mode line by line in 2nd sheet, which lane is your unexpected result?